# TimeSeriesInsert issue with Quantity expressions

Tags: units, time-series

**Solved in Mathematica v10.3**

---

This first sample code works as expected:

```
es = EventSeries@Quantity[RandomReal[1, {250}], "Meters"]
es["Values"] // Head
TimeSeriesInsert[es, {{1000, Quantity[RandomReal[], "Meters"]}}]
TimeSeries@es
UnitConvert@es["Values"] // Head
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This second sample doesn't (Windows 8.1 x64, Mathematica 10.1):

```
es = EventSeries@Quantity[RandomReal[1, {500}], "Meters"]
es["Values"]
TimeSeriesInsert[es, {{1000, Quantity[RandomReal[], "Meters"]}}]
TimeSeries@es
UnitConvert@es["Values"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Problems:

1. As already stated in another question `QuantityArray` is not displayed as of documentation.
2. `TimeSeriesInsert` returns unevaluated.
3. `EventSeries` is not converted to a TimeSeries.
4. `UnitConvert` doesn't convert the `QuantityArray` to `"SIBase"`

The problems appear related to the fact that, over a `Length` of about 250 elements, the values are internally stored as the new `QuantityArray` expression, and maybe this is not yet supported by `TimeSeriesInsert` and other functions.

Any general workaround?